# Defining variable after declaration throwing error not defined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I wanted to use a variable before its definition,

```
interface IProps extends WithStyles<typeof STYLES>;

const STYLES = () => ({ })
```

it was not causing any error, but a warning

> STYLES used before defined **`no-use-before-define`**

So I read somewhere and declare it before using, like following-

```
declare let STYLES: () => ({})

interface IProps extends WithStyles<typeof STYLES>;

STYLES = () => ({})
```

Now the console is clear, no warnings and no error, but at run time I am getting an error that

> ReferenceError: STYLES is not defined.

I have tried by making `STYLES` variable while defining, like

`let STYLES = () => ({})`

but it causing the error

> Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'STYLES'.

**So the question is, How can I define the variable before it's used without getting any warning and errors?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your tslint.json file and edit the rules part so that it looks like this

```
"rules": { 
    ...
    "no-use-before-declare": false 
    ...
}
```

Comment: Well, I want to remove the warning, not just avoid it.

Comment: I think this is the only solution I can see for now. Thanks